# "Arbitrary" generic types

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, react-typescript

Is there any TypeScript solution, that would help me have an "infinite" amount of generic types, without having to type all of them, of course?

Example bellow:

```js
type Args<T extends React.ComponentType<any>> = { component: T, presetProps: React.ComponentProps<T>};

function buildComponents<T extends React.ComponentType<any>>(...args: Args<T>[] ) : any

function componentJ({name, age}: {name: string, age: number}){
  return <h1>123</h1>
}

function componentI({ age}: { age: number}){
  return <h1>123</h1>
}

buildComponents({component:componentJ, presetProps:{name: "Jon", age: 12}}, 
                {component: componentI, presetProps:{age: 44}})
```

With this code, I got an error on `{component: componentI, presetProps:{age: 44}}`, because it misses the `name`, but I wanted this to get the type from the `componentI` and not from the the `componentJ`, which was the case.

Comment: I think you probably want to say "arbitrary" and not "infinite".

Comment: Yap, you are probably right, thanks for the heads up, I'll update the question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to make your `buildComponents` function generic not in the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of types to pass to `Args`, but in the [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) of such types.  The compiler will not want to infer a union from a heterogeneous list (where the elements may be of different types), since that is often an error:

```
function foo<T>(...args: T[]) { }
foo(1, 2, "3", 4); // error!
// -----> ~~~ string is not a number
```

On the other hand, tuple types are meant to support heterogeneous lists:

```
function bar<T extends any[]>(...args: T) {}
bar(1, 2, "3", 4); // okay
```

So let's try that with `buildComponents()`:

```
declare function buildComponents<T extends React.ComponentType<any>[]>(
  ...args: { [I in keyof T]: Args<Extract<T[I], React.ComponentType<any>>> }
): any;
```

What I've done there is to [map the tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) `T` to a new tuple, so that each element `T[I]` becomes `Args<T[I]>`.  There's a fiddly bit with [the `Extract` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) to work around a compiler bug (see [microsoft/TypeScript#27995](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27995)).  But it works:

```
buildComponents(
  { component: componentJ, presetProps: { name: "Jon", age: 12 } },
  { component: componentI, presetProps: { age: 44 } }
); // okay
```

---

Another way to do this is to make `T` the tuple of the props type and not the component type.  It is a bit cleaner:

```
declare function buildComponents<P extends any[]>(
  ...args: { [I in keyof P]: { component: React.ComponentType<P[I]>, presetProps: P[I] } }
): any;
```

and works at the call site also:

```
buildComponents(
  { component: componentJ, presetProps: { name: "Jon", age: 12 } },
  { component: componentI, presetProps: { age: 44 } }
); // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQNwCwAUAHbIhaph5ZwBSuyAGwBecAN6NGcOCzYcucAFpZiYyVLgEArk3zAITDRAgAeACoA+ABQA6W8igBzVAC44pgNoBdAJRi4AXzUpAiNLAEYAGjgAJiiAIgBmOKiAFm8aOAB6TLhlYigAQiCsnIBacvLzOAA-WrhUGChgJgc4YHQmCHhkaU0QACNlCQZ1DW1dfTh++zNcgA8YLCYAE3RkJgBPLytba3snV1NfUQDi6ahwqNi4ROS4NIzsuAgAa2QN4alAhjUZdk5cNwAPJMbjiH4jdQwDZgbgAQUcqFmWAWS1WmCoMGsAGESJBQUwYKYYVhjOsNuYqgBePy4PH6JYwQ5RMCUVBYGAABWIYBcGLwWNx4AZhO5EF5Ziq-noENGyywuAE9m4Wh0MD0Bn6mmAAmWQvxjKRpnmixW6GwApx9IJRJJZM25m2lmKUl2+z5J3cAEk2gYXlgNhACG5PK4EU5jABRBZQAVmb2eKIW-BW4U24mw+0UymnSFSbyucky4qqiYGOlpxk8SwnP5RZAObj+Vy11hYVwNJoteuN1xMPqDKABY4uuCUGCaKAGYwACzC5jC0QSxkyc-MxW+JfG6smFYNhK9NZQjYCLeP7d6A2Uw9UefU48n07Xi+Xq-nG8+6i1Or11sNzrvKQTj3EUmTgECbR4Fk2Q5MVeTPP5XDiHh9DuBsL0XAIAgiUdgL-QlXAgxkvWg9hYJ5D1z1cFIUiw75Rm8T9N0hP45EBNwAHcIFvOUFSVSgxjVDUpm1XV9VApFORNNE1k2J1RzdREz29X04H9QNg05UNaXwsDk0FXSM1JTkE3MUj2S5CjXBMr1PDo4oCxQTZizvUsd3LXTq1bNgeybBC2w7RpmgcXy+wHa9-BHQCxw5R84FnecXxXNcP1ldQ3OEoiDyPdDTz8dCwqvIdIp40YYonKd4ufJdkvfO9mNGb8xN01AALKnTKwI8DPPM8jxUoxCbhQpg0N7OBMP8bDcO6zqwKymASLgVkyMs-qzwK+5aMmyK1GY-wgA)

Comment: This is definitely what I was looking for. Hopefully there are good fellows like you around this community that share this kind of knowledge, much appreciated dude!!